# Unable to send the file in $http post method in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, form-data

In my project am trying to send the file to the server after successful upload of the file. Here is my code please check. The

```
 fdata = new FormData();
 fdata.append("file", file);

 $http.post('/UserQuestionnaire/AddQuestionnaire?Name=' + questionDetails.questionName + '&Description=' + questionDetails.questionDescription, fdata,
        {
                                    headers: {
                                     'Content-Type': false,
                                     'SessionID':$rootScope.token
                                    }
                                }).then(function(success){
                                    console.log("success question uploaded" + success);
                                },function(error){
                                  console.log("error"+error);
                                });
```

All the data is coming along with the query string value but file is not coming to the server.

Comment: Try to get $_FILES on server side.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: file is not going to the server only. Is this code is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it's not a good practice to send data in query string.

For file, you can do it in this way.

```
var fd = new FormData();
var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.uploadme);
fd.append('file', imgBlob);


$http({
    url: '/UserQuestionnaire/AddQuestionnaire',
    method: 'POST',
    data: params

});
```

Use  headers as,

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
},
```

Comment: Its an api it is designed like that. Is there any extra thing need to write in header or anywhere ?

Comment: I am trying to send a file with extension of  '.opgs'. In that case how i ll send ?

Comment: Can you provide your jsfiddle or any errors you're getting in console ?

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this in my way. This below is the updated code.

```
{
 transformRequest: angular.identity,
 headers: {
           'Content-Type': undefined,
           'SessionID':$rootScope.token
         }
}
```

This the reference link. Check this out [Multipart/form-data File Upload with AngularJS](http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)